# Drinking Water During "Shalosh Seudos"

Tags: shabbat, meal-seudah, water

Someone told me that one is not allowed to drink plain water during the third meal of Shabbos (Seudah Shelishit). (or at least that there is a minhag not to).

Is this true? And if so, what is the source of the minhag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is such a minhag, but the language of the Rema in [291:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14325&st=&pgnum=78) is:

> Some say that it is forbidden to drink
>   water between mincha and maariv on
>   shabbos because that is when the souls
>   return to purgatory (reasoning
>   needed?).  Therefore, one should not
>   eat seudah shlishis between mincha and
>   maariv, rather he should eat it before
>   mincha.
>
> Yet some say it is better to daven
>   mincha first, and such is the custom
>   in all of these provinces.  But one
>   should not drink water from the rivers
>   (reasoning needed?), but in the house
>   it is permitted, and certainly other drinks are permitted.
>
> Some say that it is only forbidden
>   within the 12 months [following the
>   death] of one's father or mother.
>
> And some say that the restriction of
>   drinking water is only on erev shabbos
>   (reasoning needed?)

We see two things from the Rema:

- The concern is not during "shalosh seudos", but between mincha and maariv time
- The Rema is all for having water during shalosh seudos even during this time.  The issue he contends with is the trade off between eating the meal + drinking water during this time and eating a meal + drinking the water before davening.

The [Aruch haShulchan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9101&st=&pgnum=141) reads the Rema as 2 opinions: Eat before mincha and eat after mincha.  The rest of the Rema is supporting opinions for eating/drinking after mincha- it's only from rivers, it's only water, some say it's only for an avel, some say it's only on Friday eve.

Answer (score 1):

Some say you should only follow this custom for *11 months* after the loved one's death, similar to how someone says kaddish for a relative for 11 months, lest you imply they were the worst type of person and need the 12 months in gehenna before entering olam haba.

Comment: When you will have accumulated enough reputation points (which will be easier if you register on the site!), you will be able to add comments. I suggest you do register, and then post your question as a separate question by clicking the "Ask Question" link atop any page. You can help make this site even more awesome. As far as this particular comment/answer (about eleven months), it's really suitable as an answer (though partial and referencing another), so I think it's okay here.

Comment: The seltzer question is quite fascinating. Can you ask it, please

Comment: @msh210 According to the [faq], all you need is 1 rep to leave a comment. Is it incorrect?

Comment: @yydl, more likely I am, though you never know.

Comment: @yydl It may be that you have to register to get this ability.

Comment: @Isaac Good point. Aside: How long should I give Yocheved, before I ask the seltzer question myself?

Comment: @yydl It's entirely up to you.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8632

Comment: Do you have a source for this?