# Does soda machshir for receiving tuma?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Would soda (non-fruit juice like sprite or coke) machshir to receive tuma? is it similar to water in this respect or to other liquids which do not machshir?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30310/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8632/759